# Q has no maximal subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Theorem: If $R$ is a ring with 1 and $I$ is a ideal in $R$ such that $I \neq R$, then there is maximal ideal $M$ of the same kind as $I$ such that $I\subseteq M$.
Note:- IF $R$ has no unity it is not true even though  $R$ is commutative. 
My question is that how to prove
$(\mathbb{Q},+)$ has no maximal sugroups.

Comment: That theorem is ultimately irrelevant here. Ideals of $\mathbb{Q}$ are not the same as subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I have proof but not getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ were a maximal proper subgroup of $\mathbb Q$, then the quotient group $\mathbb Q/A$ would be nontrivial (because $A$ is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb Q$), divisible (because $\mathbb Q$ is divisible), and therefore not cyclic.  So there's a nontrivial proper subgroup $G$ in $\mathbb Q/A$.  The inverse image of $G$ in $\mathbb Q$ is a subgroup strictly between $A$ and $\mathbb Q$, so $A$ isn't maximal after all.

Comment: More simply, but using the same idea: if $A$ is maximal in the abelian group $G$, then $G/A$ is simple, hence cyclic. No nonzero cyclic group is divisible.